# Service task node vs Domain Specific task node

Tags: drools, jbpm

What is the difference between a service task node and a domain specific node (custom work item) in jBPM?

Answer (score 0):

Service task is defined in the bpmn2 specification and custom work items are the natural extension to your own domain requirements. From the implementation point of view the Service task allows you to interact with a Java Bean or a web service directly (just via configuration) and the Custom WorkItem requires you to define a connector (by implementing the WorkItemHandler interface) that you then need to add to the application class path.

Hope this helps. 
Regards